# What is the difference between running a game and a virtual Linux OS in windows versus running Linux with a virtual OS of windows running a game?

Tags: windows, games

I have a graphic intensive game on windows. My computer can dual boot between Ubuntu and windows, but not at the same time. I theoretically have the option to run one OS as a virtual OS inside of the other. What is the difference between running a game and a virtual Linux OS in windows versus running Linux with a virtual OS of windows running a game?

Comment: What do you mean "What is the difference?"? What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You will lose a lot of speed running from any virtual environment, unfortunately. So if you run native Linux, with Windows in a virtual environment (VMWare, VirtualBox, or another one), then a program inside you lost a lot of processing, even in unity mode.

For example, think of it like this, your OS requires a fraction of your total memory/processor to keep running no matter what, the virtualizing program needs a fraction of memory, the virtual OS is given a fraction of your total memory, and the program running requires a fraction of your total memory.

It is a lot of processing power to do it honestly, and RAM. Think whatever recommended (not minimum requirements, but to run it at best quality) double or triple it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, running a game on a virtual machine cannot possibly utilise all the memory and CPU. This is because the other os still needs memory.  It (the os) isn't treated as a background service either.  It's best to run windows games on windows.  That is unless you have like 1tb of ram and Nvida GeForce Titan (or something even more powerful :P)

Answer (score 1):

Your better off playing that game in WINE.  Linux utilizes resources in more appropriate manners.  Wine just emulates without bloat-ware.